# Does System.Timers.Timer uses a seprate thread to execute timer_elapsed method

Tags: c#, timer

I am using Systems.Timers.Timer instance in a windows service. My question is that whatever is been in its Timer_Elapsed method, does that code get executed in the same thread where windows service is been run or does Timer internally execute elapsed method on a separate thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recent [blog post](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/03/all-about-net-timers-comparison.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+abhisheksur/WTgI+%28DOT+NET+TRICKS%29) by Abhishek Sur can answer your question.

In summary, `System.Timers.Timer`:

1. It invokes the available thread in ThreadPool to run the interface.
2. ThreadSafe, each eventhandler has explicit locks.
3. Can be run in any thread using ISynchronizeObject.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - but *exactly* which is a little complex ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcs6ww8.aspx)):

> If the SynchronizingObject property is null, the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread. If processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant.

But either way; it isn't your thread - code appropriately, with synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

The `Elapsed` event handlers will be executed on another thread, not the thread that started the service unless you manually specify a synchronization object to provide a synchronization context.

This is primarily targeted for Windows Forms applications, where `System.Windows.Forms.Control` (and all derived types, such as `Form`) implement the `ISynchronizeInvoke` interface and can be easily attached to the timer in order to synchronize execution. In a Windows Service environment, you'll have to code up a stub implementation of that interface that does the necessary thread synchronization, since the service provides no such implementation itself.